# pycharmでno module namedと出てimportできない

Tags: python, anaconda

pycharmでno module namedと出てimportできないです。
sklearnやlightgbmをimportしようとしていますができません。

Spyderではpython36中のsite-packeageからAnacondaのsite-packageにパッケージをコピーしたらできるようになったもののpycharmではエラーが出たままです。
（両方入れてるのがだめなのでしょうか。）

Edit configurationでanaconda中のpythonを指定しましたがだめでした。

わかる方よろしくお願いいたします。

Win10の64bitです。

Answer (score 1):

File > Settings > Project > Project Interpreter でインストール済みのライブラリが確認できるみたいです。ここのパスが意図したところになっているか確認してみて下さい。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ご回答有り難うございます。教えていただいた対応をしたところ、パッケージ一覧に目的のパッケージが出たのですがエラーは変わらないです。from sklearnと打っている途中でパッケージの場所がサジェストもされるのですが…

Comment: 追加です。ツールバーのViewを押してもScientific modeが出てこないのでnumpyも認識されていないようです。

Comment: C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\python.exeをProject interpreterに指定しましたが、状況は変わらずでした。

Comment: うーん、Project Structureの設定とかですかね。Project ExplorerのExternal Libraryにも必要なライブラリは表示されていないんですかね？

Comment: External LibraryをたどっていくとC:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\の中に入っています。
そもそもプロジェクトごとにInterpreterは設定する必要があるのでしょうか…

Comment: Scientific modeのコメントをしましたが課金していないので出現しないようですね。失礼いたしました。

Comment: 何度もすいません。Alt+Shift+EでPythonコンソールから実行だとimportしてくれるようです。